# Подскажите из за чего может быть подобное?

Tags: c#

Пишу код с использованием Дженериков на C#. 
Возник вопрос из за чего Visual Studio ругается на подобное выражение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ведь согласно MDSN при передаче параметра по ссылке out, параметр может быть не инициализирован и обязан быть инициализирован в функции. Однако Visual Studio пишет, "Использование локальное переменной ans которой не присвоено значение".

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе (**в виде текста**). Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Код должен выкладываться текстом, а не картинкой. Пожалуйте наши глаза...

Comment: да я это чисто теоретически спрашивал. Просто не понял сначала, удивился... А после того как разобрался что за глупость написал не смог удалить вопрос и ответил на него сам.

Answer (score 1):

Ключевое слово `out` нужно указывать также и при вызове метода:

```
calculator(optionData, DT_expiry_border, out ans, i);
```

Comment: Всё верно для out/ref параметров эти ключевые слова надо указывать и при вызове.